# Join array of objects to string value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo, arrayobject

I want to join array of objects to a string in python. Is there any way for me to do that?

```
url =  "https://google.com",
search = "thai food",
results = [
        {
            "restaurant": "Siam Palace",
            "rating": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "restaurant": "Bangkok Palace",
            "rating": "3.5"
        }
]
```

I want to be able to join these all to form one value.

If I could make it look like:

```
 data = {    url =  "https://google.com", 
{
   search = "thai food",
   results = [
        {
            "restaurant": "Siam Palace",
            "rating": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "restaurant": "Bangkok Palace",
            "rating": "3.5"
        }
]
}
}
```

I am receiving these results from mongodb and want to join these 3 together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JSON module

```
data = {} # create empty dict

# set the fields
data['url'] = 'https://google.com'
data['search'] = 'thai food'

# set the results
data['results'] = results

# export as string
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you a quick question. How do I create an array of these dictionaries? I have multiple of these kind of values. I want something like data = {[],[]}

Comment: can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260047/join-and-format-array-of-objects-in-python/59260243#59260243 ?