# Join and format array of objects in Python

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb, pymongo

I want to join and format values and array of objects to a string in python. Is there any way for me to do that?

```
url =  "https://google.com",
search = "thai food",
search_res = [
        {
            "restaurant": "Siam Palace",
            "rating": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "restaurant": "Bangkok Palace",
            "rating": "3.5"
        }
]
url =  "https://google.com",
search = "indian food",
search_res = [
        {
            "restaurant": "Taj Palace",
            "rating": "2.5"
        },
        {
            "restaurant": "Chennai Express",
            "rating": "5.0"
        }
]
url =  "https://bing.com",
search = "thai food",
search_res = [
        {
            "restaurant": "Siam Palace",
            "rating": "1.5"
        },
        {
            "restaurant": "Bangkok Palace",
            "rating": "4.5"
        }
]
url =  "https://bing.com",
search = "indian food",
search_res = [
        {
            "restaurant": "Taj Palace",
            "rating": "4.5"
        },
        {
            "restaurant": "Chennai Express",
            "rating": "3.0"
        }
]
```

I want to be able to format the values as such:

If I could make it look like:

```
            all_data = [{
              url = "https://google.com",
              results = [{
                search = "thai food",
                search_res = [{
                  "restaurant": "Siam Palace",
                  "rating": "4.5"
                }, {
                  "restaurant": "Bangkok Palace",
                  "rating": "3.5"
                }]
              }, {
                search = "Indian food",
                search_res = [{
                  "restaurant": "Taj Palace",
                  "rating": "2.5"
                }, {
                  "restaurant": "CHennai Express",
                  "rating": "5.0"
                }]
              }]
            }, {
              url = "https://bing.com",
              results = [{
                search = "thai food",
                search_res = [{
                  "restaurant": "Siam Palace",
                  "rating": "1.5"
                }, {
                  "restaurant": "Bangkok Palace",
                  "rating": "4.5"
                }]
              }, {
                search = "Indian food",
                search_res = [{
                  "restaurant": "Taj Palace",
                  "rating": "4.5"
                }, {
                  "restaurant": "CHennai Express",
                  "rating": "3.0"
                }]
              }]
            }, ]
```

I did this to join the values:

```
        data = {} 
        data['url'] = 'https://google.com'
        data['search'] = 'thai food'
        data['results'] = results

        import json
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

My results are joining the 3 values all together and repeats it for each of them. Is there anyway for me to format it in the format mentioned above?

Answer (score -1):

You could make a list and append each entry.

```py
    all_data = []

    data_google = {
      'url' = 'https://google.com',
      'results' = []
    }
    data_thai = {}
    data_thai['search'] = 'thai food'
    data_thai['results'] = results
    data_google.append(data_thai)

    data_indian = {}
    data_indian['search'] = 'indian food'
    data_indian['results'] = results
    data_google.append(data_indian)

    all_data.append(data_google)

    ...

    import json
    print(json.dumps(all_data , indent=4)
```

Comment: I have multiple of these... 2 values (thai and indian) are just examples. How do I do it for all. And as listed above, I want to group them by url